# I am trying to download a XLS file using visualforce page getting an error #NAME? in the downloaded file. Any inputs?

Tags: apex, visualforce, excel, contenttype

Controller Code:

```
public with sharing class XLSDemoPage_Ctrl {
    public String xlsHeader {
    get {
      String strHeader = '';
      strHeader += '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
      strHeader += '<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>';
      return strHeader;
    }
  }

    public List <SheetWrap> listSheets { get; set; }
    public XLSDemoPage_Ctrl() {
        listSheets = new List <SheetWrap>();
        List <String> lines = new List <String>();
        lines.add('<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Number</Data></Cell><Cell ss:StyleID="dateCol"><Data ss:Type="String">Total</Data></Cell>');
        lines.add('<Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">111</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(A:A)"><Data ss:Type="Number"></Data></Cell>');
        lines.add('<Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">111</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>');
        lines.add('<Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">111</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>');
        lines.add('<Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">111</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>');
        lines.add('<Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">111</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>');
        SheetWrap s1 = new SheetWrap();
        s1.rows = lines;
        listSheets.add(s1);
        System.debug('listSheets' +listSheets);     
    }

    public class SheetWrap{
    public String headers { get{ return '<Worksheet ss:Name="Demo Sheet 1">';} set; }
    public String footer { get{ return '</Worksheet>'; } set; }
    public List <String> rows { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="XLSDemoPage_Ctrl" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#Formula_Demo.xls" cache="true">
    <apex:outputText value="{! xlsHeader }"/>
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
              xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
              xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
              xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
              xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <Styles>
            <Style ss:ID="head1">
                <Alignment/>
                <Borders/>
                <Font />
                <Interior ss:Color="Yellow" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
                <NumberFormat/>
                <Protection/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="errBox">
                <Alignment />
                <Borders />
                <Font />
                <Interior ss:Color="Red" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
                <NumberFormat/>
                <Protection/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="attToVal">
                <Alignment />
                <Borders />
                <Font />
                <Interior ss:Color="#3f9ee1" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
                <NumberFormat/>
                <Protection/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="dateCol">
                <Alignment />
                <Borders />
                <Font />
                <NumberFormat ss:Format="dd/mm/yyyy" />
                <Protection/>
            </Style>
        </Styles>
        <apex:repeat value="{! listSheets }" var="sheet">
            <apex:outputText value="{! sheet.headers }" escape="false"/>
            <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
                <apex:repeat value="{! sheet.rows }" var="row">
                    <Row>
                        {!row}
                    </Row>
                </apex:repeat>
            </Table>
            <apex:outputText value="{! sheet.footer }" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </Workbook>
</apex:page>
```

After the file got downloaded when I am opening the file getting the error #NAME? in the cell as shown below

[image]

Appreciate any input on how to mitigate this issue.

Comment: You are introducing a  formula in cell B2 of `=SUM(A:A)` but cell A1 is not a number. Could that be it?

Comment: Actually, the cell ended up =SUM(A:(A)) something like this in the output. I am sure A1 may not be the problem in this case.